# Energy gap of $In_{0.53}Ga_{0.24}Al_{0.23}As_{0.77}$

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Does anybody know how can I calculate the energy gap of  $In_{0.53}Ga_{0.24}Al_{0.23}As_{0.77}$ ?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369698/2451

Comment: This sort of information might be known to the makers of such material or companies selling devices based on it.  You should contact them.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to look would be Akio Sasaki et al., "Energy Band Structure and Lattice Constant Chart of III-V Mixed Semiconductors, and AlGaSb/AlGaAsSb Semiconductor Lasers on GaSb Substrates", [Japanese Journal of Applied Physics 19(9) 1695-1702 (1980)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1143/JJAP.19.1695/meta). They provide the equations and parameters to calculate quaternary band gaps, along with contour plots.